# ANSI C Parser - C Compiler - Looking for switch statements

Tags: c++, parsing, reverse-engineering

***CONTEXT***

I am writing a ANSI C code parser. The objective is to find finite state machine implementations in c code and reverse engineer to create documentation on existing states and event transfers.

There are mainly 3 common implementations of finite state machines in c code that we need to look for: using nested switch statements (outer level switches on state inner level switches on event), 2D array of structs each containing a function pointer and next state (after transition function is executed), and 1D array of function pointers and 2D array of states.

The main goal is finite state machine detection.

To detect a state machine within nested switch statements, I am writing a c parser in c++ to extract all switch statements from c source code and to store them in a parent-child-sibling relationship that exists in my code.

***ISSUE***

The issue is with a module in my c parser that is suppose to extract switch statements from c source code and store it in a parent-child-sibling relationship that exists in my code.

***PROGRAM OUTPUT***

when run on a list of 89 c source code files my program will work fine and extract many of the switch statements but it will break seemingly randomly.

*debug_output.txt*

https://file.io/IDy4Hj

The file contains an output of each extracted switch statement from a list of 89 c source code files.

You will see that it breaks about halfway through from an unknown error.

***MY ANSI C switch statement parser***

A simular overloaded function exists with this signature

`std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, SwitchStatements&)`

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, SwitchStatements * ss)
{
    assert(ss != nullptr);
    using namespace std;
    is.setstate(ios::goodbit);
    string str;
    while (is >> str)
    {
        if (str.find("switch") != string::npos) {
            ss->appendBuffer(str);
            int bracket_counter = 0;
            char c = '0';
            while ((c = is.get()) != EOF) {
                ss->appendBuffer(c);
                /* error handling */
                try {
                    if (bracket_counter < 0)
                        throw std::exception{ "bracket counter cannot be less than 0" };
                    if (c == '}' && bracket_counter == 0)
                        throw std::exception{ "error cannot meet closing bracket before opening" };
                    if (c == EOF && bracket_counter != 0)
                        throw std::exception{ "error cannot meet eof before all closing brackets" };
                }
                catch (std::exception _e) {
                    cerr << "exception: ";
                    Beep(750, 1000);
                    cerr << _e.what() << endl;
                    cin.get();
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
                }
                /* end error handling */
                if (c == '{')bracket_counter++;
                if (c == '}')bracket_counter--;
                if (c == '}' && !bracket_counter) {
                    ss->setOffset(is.tellg());
                    assert(bracket_counter == 0);
                    return is;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    is.setstate(ios::badbit);
    return is;
}
```

Here is my constructor.
What I do here is allow the constructor to be constructed with source code,
it then will recursively construct new SwitchStatements and add them to the appropriate vector sibling or children.

```
SwitchStatements::SwitchStatements(std::unique_ptr<std::string> _considering)
{
    using namespace std;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << *_considering;
    ss >> this;
    if (ss.good())
    {
        stringstream ss_child;
        string buf_sub = this->buffer.substr(this->buffer.find_first_of('{'));
        ss_child << buf_sub;
        SwitchStatements ss_switch;
        while (ss_child >> ss_switch)
        {
            SwitchStatements ss_switch_child(
                make_unique<string>(string{ ss_switch.buffer })
            );
            if (!ss_switch_child.buffer.empty() || 
                !ss_switch_child.getSibling().empty())
                children.push_back(ss_switch_child);
            ss_child.clear();
            ss_switch_child.clearAll();
        }
        siblings.push_back(SwitchStatements(
            make_unique<string>(string{ (*_considering).substr(offset) })
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: ... if you're serious at all, you will at least need a proper C lexer.

Comment: Immediately apparent problem: you do not correctly skip string literals and comments, both of which can contain `switch`, `{` or `}` and would break your parser.

Comment: The file.io link seems to be broken

Comment: Why do you write a parser for an 28 year old, obsolete version of the standard? Better write a parser for standard C. And a state-machine to parse C is not really a good idea.

Comment: @Olaf, this corresponds to the kind of work that needs to be done to modernize an old code base.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: @Olaf this is contracting work for a large manufacturer of telecommunication equipment that writes all their firmware in ANSI C.   Over the years they have amassed large volumes of firmware that does not contain any documentation other than comments. This work will help modernize their old code base with supporting documentation relevant to existing finite state machines and event transfers.

Comment: @yurikilochek I failed to mention that I have pre-parsed the files to exclude any comments, but I did not think to skip string literals, so I think that's the problem, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing C parser, such as the clang API?

Comment: @sepp2k didn't think to use one because the parsing functionality I need is minimal, but it would ensure reliability, so it's a good idea.